# Remove Duplicate from v-for

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a issue on my project. Its repeated item on filter list.

I want remove all duplicate items on my list.

output result:

[image]

```js
 export default {
  name: "ShowBlogs",
  data() {
    return {
      blogs: [],
      search: "",
      UnitType: "",
      PropertyName: "",
      areCommunity: "",
      AdType: ""
    };
  },

  created() {
    this.$http.get("http://localhost:3000/Listing").then(function(data) {
      console.log(data);

      this.blogs = data.body;
    });
  },

 computed: {
    filteredList() {
      const { blogs, search, UnitType } = this;
      return this.blogs
        .filter(blog => blog.Unit_Type.includes(this.UnitType))
        .filter(blog => blog.Community.includes(this.areCommunity))

        .filter(blog => blog.Ad_Type.includes(this.AdType));
    },
    };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

  <select
                      v-model="PropertyName"
                      id="formInput200"
                      class="form-control"
                      value="Buildingname"
                    >
                      <option disabled value>Building Name</option>
                      <option
                        v-for="blog in blogs"
                        v-bind:value="blog.Property_Name"
                        :key="blog.id"
                      >{{ blog.Property_Name}}</option>
                    </select>
```

How can I remove this from my list?

Comment: you could make another computed property where you filter for unique names and loop over those in the v-for

Comment: It is better to fix it from backend so you do not receive unused data.

Comment: @dave its working Thank you

 filteradtype() {
      return _.uniqBy(this.blogs, function(u) {
        return u.Unit_Type;
      });
    },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Its working on this code 
Thank You @Dave*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mp0zk.png)

```
<select
                  v-model="UnitType"
                  id="UnitType"
                  class="form-control"
                  aria-placeholder="Property type"
                >
                  <option disabled value>Property Type</option>
                  <option
                    v-for="blog in  filteradtype"
                    v-bind:value="blog.Unit_Type"
                    :key="blog.id"
                  >{{ blog.Unit_Type}}</option>
                </select>



 filteradtype() {
  return _.uniqBy(this.blogs, function(u) {
    return u.Unit_Type;
  });
},
```